# Invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "NOW() - INTERVAL '12 hours'"

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, timescaledb

I'm trying to make a query based on a field ``time` to get the last week data:

```
Measure::where('time', '>', "NOW() - INTERVAL '12 hours'")->get();
```

but I can't make it work.

```
I get this message: 

SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "NOW() - INTERVAL '12 hours'" (SQL: select * from "measures" where "time" > NOW() - INTERVAL '12 hours')
```

Thing is I get this condition from [official docs](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/reading-data#select) of timescaleDB, supposed to be postgres compatible:

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM conditions WHERE time > NOW() - INTERVAL '12
> hours';

Why is it happening, and what should I do ?

Comment: what's the datatype of the `time` column?

Comment: it is a timestamp in postgres

Comment: I think the issue is with double quotes , try writing the without it using the escape character for single quotes for writing 12 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you  need to use whereRaw because you have function calls in your expression.

```
Measure::whereRaw("time > NOW() - INTERVAL '12 hours'")->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `hour` without quotes

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM conditions WHERE time > NOW() - INTERVAL 12 hour;
```