# Laravel subquery for MAX date - Invalid datetime format in subquery link with parent

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-query-builder

The following query is returning the above error:

```
$readings = MeterReading::where('meters_readings.meter_id', $m->meter_id)
        ->where('meters_readings.read_local_at', '>=', function($query) use ($m) {
            $query->selectRaw('MAX(flow_readings.read_local_at)')
                ->from('flow_readings')
                ->where('flow_readings.meter_id', $m->meter_id)
                ->where('flow_readings.read_local_at', '<=', 'meters_readings.read_local_at');
        })->orderBy('meters_readings.read_local_at', 'DESC')
        ->first();
```

The problem seems to be the subquery timestamp comparison. It complains that the parent table timestamp is of invalid input syntax. If I replace it with a timestamp string, ('2018-05-05 12:25:30') it works.

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @miken32, I changed the question as there is an issue now with the subquery parent timestamp.

Comment: FWIW, this seems like something that could be accomplished with much cleaner code using Eloquent relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to the above from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63057183/invalid-input-syntax-for-type-timestamp-now-interval-12-hours). Adding `Raw` to the subquery timestamp comparison fixed it.

```
$readings = MeterReading::where('meters_readings.meter_id', $m->meter_id)
        ->where('meters_readings.read_local_at', '>=', function($query) use ($m) {
            $query->selectRaw('MAX(flow_readings.read_local_at)')
                ->from('flow_readings')
                ->where('flow_readings.meter_id', $m->meter_id)
                ->whereRaw('flow_readings.read_local_at <= meters_readings.read_local_at');
        })->orderBy('meters_readings.read_local_at', 'DESC')
        ->first();
```